# Как поменять url в адресной строке браузера с помощью js?

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим клиент находится на странице интернет-магазина

`https://site.ru/product-category/kriuchki/?search=&price_min=0&price_max=1051&page=2`

Необходимо, чтобы когда он выбирал другой тип сортировки товаров на странице, его кидало на первую страницу каталога. Как я могу убрать `page=2` и перезагрузить страницу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Убрать можно через обработку адреса как строки (но рекомендую посмотреть в сторону парсеров), пример:

```js
let url = 'https://site.ru/product-category/kriuchki/?search=&price_min=0&price_max=1051&page=2';
console.log(url.replace(/&page=\d+/, ''));
```

Страница будет перезагружена при изменении [window.location.href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/href)

Полный пример:

```
let url = window.location.href;
window.location.href = url.replace(/&page=\d+/, '');
```

Comment: А возможно как-то это сделать с сохранением типа сортировки? Реплейс работает, но он также сбрасывает установленную юзером сортировку

Comment: @RamzanGadamurov, думаю, вам нужно и значение сортировки хранить в url, чтобы при удалении `page` и перехода на страницу значение сортировки сохранилось

Answer (score 2):

Если фильтр из себя представляет простую форму с GET-запросом, то можно внедрить в него поле со значением текущей страницы. При изменении параметров фильтра просто устанавливать значение этого поля как `1`

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.filter__field').forEach((input)=>{
  input.addEventListener('input',(e)=>{
    input.form.elements.page.value = 1;
  })
})
```

```html
<form action="" class="filter">
    <input type="number" name="price_min" class="filter__field" placeholder="Цена от" min="0" max="100">
    <input type="number" name="price_max" class="filter__field" placeholder="Цена до" min="1" max="100">
    <input type="hidden" name="page" value="2">
    <button>Применить фильтр</button>
</form>
```